# How to apply for 4G memory size for WASM in Electron?

Tags: node.js, electron, chromium, webassembly

When I used
`
app.commandLine.appendSwitch('js-flags', '--max-old-space-size=4096');

`
to implement that, it didn't seem to work well as the memory of render process did become to 4G. I have already applied in WASM output file but nothing changed.

Is there any other chromium commands or way to implement that?